# What .NET frameworks should I use to build a stand-alone program for Windows 7 and later?

Tags: windows, c#, .net

More specifically, I want to build a stand-alone C# program that runs on Windows 7 and later, but without having to bother the user with having to find a .NET installer package first.

A different way to word my question is, are any of the .NET frameworks installed by default in Windows 7 and later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different OS's will have different framework versions by default. The latest version (v4.7.x) can be installed on Windows 7 onwards.

However, so far every OS from Windows 7 can have v3.5.1 installed (via Programs & Features), so that it probably makes this the 'route of least resistence' for now, but this may change in future.

But if you want longevity, working against v4.7 will provide the best 'future-proofing' but will require older Windows versions to have this manually installed.
[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/)

Comment: It seems that the outdated C/C++ and Win32 is still the best way to write apps that run easily in this way.